# How to manually do what Putty on Windows does?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, tunnel

I have a Putty session login (SSH) and a tunnel created. How does one do that manually? What does a putty UI translate to in practice?

For example, my putty session looks like a normal `ssh usernam@some.domain.com` - seems to work that way.
But, what about those tunnels in Connection->SSH->Tunnels where I have, for example: `L9901 245.202.190.30:2201` as an entry?

How do I do all that manually on OSX or Linux?

I've tried doing:
`ssh username@mydomain.com -t ssh -L9901:localhost:2201` but that failed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the behavior by doing a

```
ssh -L 9901:245.202.190.30:2201 username@mydomain.com
```

Comment: Looks to be working. Can you explain to me what is the difference of this and if I wrote:
ssh -L 9901:localhost:2201 username@245.202.190.30

For example, when I need to make chained tunnels, I've noticed I need to use that way to actually make a tunnel from 245.202.190.30's port 2201 to local 9901. Otherwise thing simply doesn't work (ssh -L 9901:245.202.190.30:2201 username@245.202.190.30 does not work).

I was under impression the address between ports is what I'm trying to tunnel from to my machine.

Comment: My command translates: bind local port 9901 to port 2201 of 245.202.190.30 using account username on "mydomain.com"  as gateway. Your command translates to bind local port 9901 to local port 2201 on 245.202.190.30

Comment: Hmm. Because when I was trying to tunnel host3 to host2 and host2 to host1, I had to go with: 
ssh -v -L81:localhost:81 host1user@host1-IP -t ssh -v -L81:localhost:81 host2user@host2-IP -t ssh -v -L81:localhost:80 host3user@host3-IP

to get host3 web service visible on host1 and eventually a machine that sshs to host1.

This is what I followed and it worked. http://ufasoli.blogspot.hr/2013/11/multi-hop-ssh-tunnel-howto-creating-ssh.html

Why? Because, as you explained already, it doesn't make much sense to map local port to local port to achieve diff machines tunneling... or does it?